# class file option: switch endnote to footnote

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm working on a class file where notes are endnotes by default but can be converted to footnotes through a class option (this is because some prominent journals in my field require that submissions come with endnotes; this is ostensibly to make life easier for their typesetters, but given that endnotes are a pain to read, the first thing everybody does before uploading papers to a repository is change the endnotes to the footnotes). A minimal class file looks as follows

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[18/05/2015, MWE]

\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{endnotes}

\DeclareOption{endnotes}{\let\footnote=\endnote}
\DeclareOption{footnotes}{}

\ExecuteOptions{endnotes}
\ProcessOptions
```

And the MWE `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{mwe}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum\footnote{First footnote}
\lipsum\footnote{Second footnote}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Compiling `mwe.tex` without a class option or with the `endnotes` option produces two endnotes, as expected. However, compiling it with the `footnote` option eliminates all notes, even if I also delete the `\theendnotes` line.

What is the best way of implementing this option?

Comment: Make the `endnotes` option load the `endnotes` package, and otherwise not, might be a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could conditionally load the endnotes package

mwe.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[18/05/2015, MWE]

\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}
\LoadClass{article}

\newif\if@endnotes

\DeclareOption{endnotes}{\@endnotestrue}
\DeclareOption{footnotes}{\@endnotesfalse}

\ExecuteOptions{endnotes}
\ProcessOptions

\if@endnotes
\RequirePackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\fi

\providecommand\theendnotes\relax
```

You can create a conditional to keep track of the which type of notes are to be used

```
\newif\if@endnotes
```

Then after processing the options you conditionally load the endnotes package:

```
\if@endnotes
\RequirePackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\fi
```

You can't just load the package inside the option because packages can't be loaded at that point in a class file.

Finally, so you can leave `\theendnotes` in your document even when using footnotes, make the class define it if it isn't already defined:

```
\providecommand\theendnotes\relax
```